# Not able to clone ngx-admin

Tags: ngx-admin

I am not able to do clone the ngx admin using the below mentioned command
git clone https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git

Getting this error after the git clone command:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I tried to search for solutions on stackoverflow but did not find anything. I tried to clone it but its not working. Would appreciate if some one could guide me.